# Do any non-human species have packed abs?

Tags: human-anatomy, anatomy

The classic "six-pack abs" in humans is due to tendons stretched across the abdominal muscles and low body fat. Do any other animals have a similar arrangement of tendons that could result in visible "n-pack abs" for a sufficiently low body fat individual?

Comment: Most animals are quadripedal and therefore their abdomens are generally not exposed. Perhaps the tendinous intersections required for the abdominal flexibility required for a bipedal posture. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tendinous_intersection#Physiological_function).